# AdMob Creates multiple adverts. OnDestroy not called

Tags: java, android, admob

I have adMob running on my app and everytime I go to another activity and return to the main one. Instead of refreshing the already created ad a new advert is added. So Slowly multiple adverts are pushing out my app.

I am running

```
    adView.destroy();
```

In onDestroy and at the start of onResume now but both seem to have no effect.

What should I try?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to the fact I was initiating the ads from the onResume and not onCreate